# click event is not triggering on input element from ref

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ref

I am using react 17.0.2 and material ui 4.11.4

I want to customize the select element appearnce (like Chip component of material ui). For this purpose I am using Autocoomplete component which renders an input element. I have rendered Chip component below the input element.

I am also getting the `ref` in the `renderInput` callback function which I am ustlising to trigger input click from Chip component.

When I log the `params.inputProps.ref.current` I am indeed getting the input element but calling click function does not show the dropdown but just focus the input element. When I click the input directly then it shows the dropdown.

I have created a sandbox of this behaviour.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-select-label-si2wb?file=/src/Demo1.js:1103-1132)

Comment: So when they click the published chip, you want the dropdown menu to show for the input box?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using state as a controlled component.

```
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const statusDropdownInput = useRef(null);
  let [val, setVal] = useState(false) // <- Store the open state

  const handleStatusDropdownClick = (params,e) => {
    setVal(!val) // <- Will toggle the dropdown
  };

  let inputElement = null
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      className={classes.statusDropdown}
      id="status"
      open={val} // <- Control the input elements state here
      options={["Option 1", "Option 2"]}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
          <input type="text" {...params.inputProps} />
          <Chip
            size="small"
            avatar={<DoneOutlinedIcon />}
            label="Published"
            clickable
            onDelete={() => {
              console.log(params.inputProps);
            }}
            onClick={(e) => handleStatusDropdownClick(params)}
            deleteIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```